# Having problems with fseek() in C

Tags: c, fseek

So, I have this function on my program that is supposed to save a "car_str" structure into the desired place on a file specified as a parameter. But when I run it, it keeps overwriting the first slot again and again, as if fseek didn't point to the specified place on the file. Is there any problem with my code? I think it may be related with the multiplication, since without it the program does well, but I cannot point to the place I want.

```
void save(int car_nbr)
{
    FILE *f;

    f = fopen("memory.txt","wb");
    if (!f)
    {
        printf ("error");
    }
    else
    {
        car_nbr--;
        fseek(f, sizeof(struct car_str)*car_nbr, SEEK_SET);
        fwrite(&car,sizeof(struct car_str),1,f);
        rewind(f);
        fclose(f);
        printf("\nsaved");
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the multiplication give you?

Comment: `fseek` has a return value that tells you if it succeeded.  You should check the return value.  Is it what you expect?

Comment: it's supposed to give the size in bytes of (car_nbr) times my structure

Comment: i checked the return value, and it's 0

Comment: Is chr_nbr what you think it is? Your code looks ok, maybe it's inthe caller. You really should look at the return value of fseek and fwrite though.

Comment: idk, i'll try to compile it elsewhere, i've been having problems with windows 8 and compilers lately.

Answer (score 0):

you need to fopen with r+b.

if you fail than file not exist, so you can try use "wb"

"w" - write: Create an empty file for output operations. If a file with the same name already exists, its contents are discarded and the file is treated as a new empty file.

"r+" - read/update: Open a file for update (both for input and output). The file must exist.

```
 f = fopen("memory.txt","r+b");
```

Comment: tried and still not working, I don't think that's the problem, since I only write in this function.

Comment: size_t pos = ftell (f); will tell you the read/write position in the file.

Comment: it worked for me perfectly, only reason you see just one item is the opening with "wb".

Comment: I think I found the problem, it's on another function though haha.